# Where to find shell_exec to enable or disable it?

Tags: shell-exec

I have a tube with MechBunny script on it, and the encoder is not running at all. The developer said it is because shell_exec being blocked. I quote: "you most likely have shell_exec on the list of disabled functions in php"

[image]

Tried searching in php.ini, but I only see this:

```
disable_functions=
```

How can I find shell_exec and enable or disable it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit php.ini file.

Look for the line which contains: (your line might be having more functions listed, this is just an example)

```
disable_functions = "show_source, system, shell_exec, exec"
```

And remove shell_exec from that list.

When you are finished editing your php.ini, you will need to restart your Apache server.

Comment: My disable_functions is blank upon opening the file, but php_info() still shows it as disabled. Is there somewhere else this would be?

Comment: @NeoTechni how did you solve the problem?